# Is it possible to use 2 rotary encoders at once?

Tags: control, encoder, rotary

I'm working on this project: http://www.corsaclube.com.br/viewtopic.php?t=102183
I'm basically installing an iPad mini on the dash of my new car, but I'm facing a problem:
The iPad doesn't offer volume control when it's in Dock Mode and the head unit will be hidden behind the Tablet.
I was thinking in solder a second and identical rotary encoder as a "parasit" on the original one for the volume control, so I install that second one somewhere handy on the dash. The rotary encoder my head unity uses isn't optical, it's the "clicky" one (same feel of the scrolling wheel on some computer mouses, sorry for my ignorance)

Will it work? If not, how can I do that?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how you intend to use the two encoders. Could you perhaps provide a sketch? What does "parasit" mean? Perhaps there is a language barrier here as I don't speak spanish/portuguese.

Comment: He's basically asking if he can wire a 2nd encoder in parallel with the 1st one to have both control the volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general this may not be possible easily. The usual mechanical encoder connection appears as two switches with a common connection. Usually the common connection is connected to GND and the other two connections go to pullup resistors and to inputs on a micro.

The problem is that many encoders are **not** guaranteed to have both switches 'off' when they are at rest in the detent position. I have specified some that do not have a guaranteed state on one of the outputs in the detent position (could be open or could be closed). That allows looser tolerances on the manufacturing and will be more common on encoders with many pulses per revolution.

I suggest it might be easiest and most straightforward to wire a small DPDT toggle switch to switch between the two encoders. DPDT is enough- you can parallel the momentary switches (if present) and the encoder grounds can be connected together.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the first is configured. If it connects the output to ground and uses a pullup resistor to hold the output normally high (or vice versa) then it is possible to put a similar device in parallel.

The tricky part is finding a device that uses the same output encoding. Some are pulse per detent, some are two pulses per detent. Make sure that the new device matches the original device's encoding exactly.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to can work but you are going to have to do some cut & patch wiring.

The problem is that your existing rotary encoder has 4 possible states: 00, 01, 10, 11

Where a "1" means the encoder has an OPEN switch contact and a "0" means that the switch contact is closed.  Note that I'm using active LO terminology because most encoders are wired with the switches to ground and pull-up resistors providing the "1".

If you were to simply wire the encoders in parallel, you have a 25% chance of the encoder on the head unit being in the "11" position and allowing your external encoder to work correctly.

I see two easy ways to fix this but they both involve cutting the traces to the existing encoder.

1) Use a 3.5mm stereo mini jack on the head unit and wire the existing encoder to the normally-closed contacts on the jack.  The jack Tip & Ring connections go to the circuit where the existing encoder used to connect.

Then simply connect your external encoder to a 3.5mm plug and connect it to the head unit when needed.  When you pull the connector for the external encoder, the jack normals the internal encoder connections to the circuit and everything works correctly.

2) Use a small microcontroller such as one of the PIC 12F family.  This controller has a total of 1- Input-Only and 5- I/O lines available.  The input and one of the I/O lines goes to the external encoder, 2 more I/O lines go to the internal encoder, the last 2 I/O lines go to the circuit.

Write some code such that any movement on either encoder passes those signals through to the  circuit and ignores signals from the other encoder.

Simply rotating one encoder or the other causes the microcontroller to switch to that encoder.  You'll have to decide what to do if both encoders are turned at the same time - personally, I'd simply ignore the external encoder in that situation.

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought you could sum the two-digit binary outputs of the two encoders to combine them, using 2 bits from an adder like the 4-bit full adder [74LS83](http://www.cs.smith.edu/~thiebaut/270/datasheets/sn74ls83arev5.pdf). But the quadrature encoder outputs are actually in gray code, so that won't work. You'll need a truth table like this instead:

```
    | 00 01 11 10
----+------------
 00 | 00 01 11 10
 01 | 01 11 10 00
 11 | 11 10 00 01
 10 | 10 00 01 11
```

The table can be shifted without affecting the performance of the encoders.

Rather than building a custom truth table it may be easier to convert both encoder outputs from gray code to usual binary by XORing the second digit with the first:

```
  -->
00 | 00
01 | 01
11 | 10
10 | 11
```

Then use binary addition:

```
    | 00 01 10 11
----+------------
 00 | 00 01 10 11
 01 | 01 10 11 00
 10 | 10 11 00 01
 11 | 11 00 01 10
```

And for output, convert back to gray code using the same XORing method:

```
  -->
00 | 00
01 | 01
10 | 11
11 | 10
```

If you don't do this on a microprocessor, this takes 3 XOR gates from a quad XOR gate such as the [MC14070B](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MC14070B-D.PDF). It may be useful to read the possibly noisy rotary encoder signals through single gates so that there is an agreement on their logical value. To do this and to further filter noise you can add an inverting or noninverting quad Schmitt trigger such as the quad NAND Schmitt [CD4093B](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4093b.pdf). You may need pullup/down resistors depending on how the rotary encoder is constructed.

Noise can be a problem in this approach, as summing the output of two rotary encoders doubles the maximum numerical peak-to-peak noise from 1 bit to 2 bits. This may confuse the device being controlled. It may be better and easier to use a microprocessor to select for output one of the rotary encoders when both of its gray code signal lines have changed state since de-selecting it, indicating that it was rotated more than could be expected from a noise spike.

Comment: I think the right approach is likely to be using a microcontroller to decode both wheels, extend the two-bit value from each to at least 3 bits (may as well do 8), add the results together, and then convert the result back to quadrature form with some logic to ensure that if increasing values are "clockwise" and the count instantly goes from e.g. 29 to 31, the system's encoder output behaves as though the encoder was rotated clockwise two clicks slowly enough for the other side to see it.